# Carregar fragment usando tablayout

Tags: android

Tenho alguns *fragments* com `TableLayout`, está nessa ordem:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Eu usei o método `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5)` quando crio meu `viewPager`.

Até aqui ok, eu não quero que ele fique carregando toda hora os *fragments* e o `seOffscreenPageLimit` resolveu isso para mim. Porém eu preciso que o *fragment* 1 recarregue toda vez que chegar nele.

Alguém tem alguma solução para isso? ou já sofreu com algo parecido? Obrigado

Comment: Consegue explicar melhor qual é o problema? `setOffscreenPageLimit(5)`, ao contrario do que diz, mantém todos os fragments em memória. O que quer dizer com "recarregue"?

Comment: exato, ele mantém todos meus fragments na memória, e pelo que vi no ciclo de vida, ele nunca entra no onCreateView do fragment, até ai perfeito.

Meu problema é, eu quero deixar todos fragments na memória, não preciso que fique entrando no onCreateView, porém eu preciso que o fragment 1 sempre entre no onCreateView para eu recarregar a minha webview.

Comment: Crie um método no fragment em causa e coloque nele o código que recarrega a WebView. Use o código da resposta do thiagoms83 e quando for seleccionada essa página chame esse método.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método setOnPageChangeListener de ViewPager para saber quando o usuário está na posição 1:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            //verifique se usuario esta na posicao 0 e atualize o fragment
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
```

Comment: Eu não entendi aonde posso implementar isso, atualmente eu tenho um setupViewPager e chamo um adapter, eu coloco esse codigo no adapter?